# Why are there module files like [modulename].pages.inc?

Tags: 7

I start to learning moding Drupal and I have a look for the current ones. There are files like [modulename].pages.inc or [modulename].api.inc and I can't find why it exists? I read that base files are only [modulename].module, [modulename].info, [modulename].install in Drupal book.

Can somebody explain me these files or post names all this kind files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a convention used for separating logic out of the main .module file.

The [modulename].pages.inc file typically contains page callback functions (those defined in [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)). Since these functions aren't used in every page request there's no point including them, so they're auto-included from the `file` property defined in `hook_menu()` when needed.

You'll probably come across [modulename].admin.inc too, which typically contains callback functions for admin pages.

[modulename].api.php is another convention that Drupal core uses (and subsequently a lot of contrib modules use) to show examples of the hooks they provide, and usually how to use them.

There are other [modulename].[group].inc files that can be auto-included when another module implements [`hook_hook_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_hook_info/7):

> Normally hooks do not need to be explicitly defined. However, by declaring a hook explicitly, a module may define a "group" for it. Modules that implement a hook may then place their implementation in either $module.module or in $module.$group.inc. If the hook is located in $module.$group.inc, then that file will be automatically loaded when needed. In general, hooks that are rarely invoked and/or are very large should be placed in a separate include file, while hooks that are very short or very frequently called should be left in the main module file so that they are always available.

Comment: Doing this can help with the memory footprint, as files  are only loaded if they are actually needed for a particular request.